# Names not adding to list

Tags: 2010, list, active-directory, sharepoint-workspace

In sharepoint workspace I want to add names to my 'IM contact' field in one of my lists. When I click the address icon and search for a name, the name appears. It lets me add it, then when I click `ok` to add it doesn't actually add ot to the field.

Adding names the same way works fine over the web client, but not on workspace. I'm sure it should be fine, it seems buggy. Sometimes it will work but mostly it wont. It's all on the same site.

Any idea why? I'm using sharepoint workspace 2010.

[image]